# Passing command line options from NASM to C

Tags: c, arguments, stack, nasm

I have an assembly file that calls a C  function that takes the arguments `int argc, char *argv[]`, with the assumption that what *should* already be on the stack (the command line arguments) will be passed to the function. But instead, it segfaults the moment the function is called. Any wisdom?

Assembly:

```
extern func
; stuff over here
_start:
        call func ; nothing manually pushed into stack.
; stuff over here
```

C:

```c
struct of_my_creation func(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  printf("check"); // never runs; SIGSEGV comes first.
}
```

OS: Parrot Linux

Compiler: GCC 10

Architecture: x86-64

Thanks.

Comment: To get any kind of quality response you need to show what you did, and on both sides of the fence, so that your use of calling conventions, and so on, can be reviewed.

Comment: You may need to know the ABI your C compiler used to generate `of_my_creation`  function. That is: how input/output arguments are read/written and where. Many ABIs uses registers and not stack for result and first arguments. Analyzing resulting assembly may help too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to A. Loiseau

Passing the arguments into `rdi` and `rsi` instead of stack worked.

New assembly:

```
extern func
; stuff over here
_start:
        pop rdi
        lea rsi, [rsp]
        call func
; stuff over here
```